# Is it possible to highlight part of a colspan column in CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, background, background-color

I have an HTML table that looks something like this:

[image]

I've set the colors using colgroups.

```
  <colgroup>
    <col style="background-color:lightgrey">
    <col style="background-color:white">
    <col style="background-color:lightgrey">
  </colgroup>
```

What I'd like is to have a striped table, where columns alternate colors and for this to take effect in the colspan rows. I.e. I want something like this:

[image]

What's the easiest way for me to achieve this?

Thanks

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kq1hnmuw/7/

Comment: Do you want to try like this? https://jsfiddle.net/uxzd1cpr/

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for me. My use-case is a bit more complex than the example here, which I used for simplicity sake. In my case I have a div element inside the colspan that needs to use colspan to span more than one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this would work for your actual table, but you could maybe try something like this:

```css
table {
  overflow:hidden;
}
tr:first-child > th {
  position:relative;
}
tr:first-child > th::before {
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:-1000px; /* i.e. minus of any value that is greater than the height of your table */
  background-color:lightgrey;
  z-index:-1;
}
tr:first-child > th:nth-child(2)::before {
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<table border>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>Jack</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
    <td>Andrew</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Sum: $180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess we need your accuracy here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58434604/8620333 ;)