# Does anonymous inline box contain whitespace?

Tags: css, specifications, w3c

I read about CSS2.1 Specification, and in ["Anonymous inline boxes"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous) section, it shows an example of anonymous inline boxes like this:

```html
<p>Some <em>emphasized</em> text</p>
```

and it says:

> the <p> generates a block box, with several inline boxes inside it. The box for "emphasized" is an inline box generated by an inline element (<em>), but the other boxes ("Some" and "text") are inline boxes generated by a block-level element (<p>). The latter are called anonymous inline boxes because they do not have an associated inline-level element.

then my question is why anonymous inline boxes' contents are "Some" and "text" not something like "Some " and " text" include whitespace?

and what's the meaning of the following paragraph?

> White space content that would subsequently be collapsed away according to the 'white-space' property does not generate any anonymous inline boxes.

what's the meaning of "be collapsed away"?

Comment: it means if you have multiple white-spaces next to each other, only one will show unless you  use css like `white-space: pre` to make them show

Comment: another question to be added: is the white space algorithm applied before or after  creating anonymous box? This may complete your *puzzle*.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah, I think so

Comment: You are right. The anonymous inline box contents would be "Some " and " text".

Comment: @Alohci Then why whitespaces are not included in the example of CSS2.1 Specification?

Comment: @looknico - I don't know, but at a guess, I'd say that in a paragraph that's more illustrative than normative, the purpose of "Some" and "text" is to indicate *where* the anonymous inline boxes are, rather than defining their contents.

Comment: @Alohci so if I consider the following code `<div><span>Hello</span> <span>World</span></div>`, there is an anonymous box that contain the space between the two spans?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - in the absence of any other css, correct.  You could add `span:first-child::after { content: ' ' }` and the space between the spans would be collapsed into the first span, in which case there wouldn't be an anonymous box between them. (You could also then add `span:first-child::after { font-size:0 }` and hide the gap between "Hello" and "World" altogether. Sadly that only works with `display:inline` elements, not inline-block ones.)

Comment: @Alohci thanks, so basically we first run the white-space algorithm then we identify the boxes, intresting. I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: @TemaniAfif. I think it would have to be that order. At the end of each line, the browser needs to know where to break the text into inline boxes, one for the end of one line and one for the start of the next. It wouldn't know where (or even if) to do that until after it had collapsed the white-space.

Answer (score -1):

The whitespace is just space, it is not styled and cannot be targeted therefore the mention of it is not useful. They only mention it to remind us that if you only had whitespace, such as 5 whitespaces they will all collapse and show only one. And it will still not be able to be targeted but worth the mention.

If there was no words such as "some" and "text" in that example then only white space would appear. But since whitespace cannot be styled and is not a block or inline element then it would just collapse. In other words, no need to worry about whitespace as it is not an element.

Comment: _“In other words, no need to worry about whitespace as it is not an element.”_ - and what exactly does this have to do with what was actually asked here? “some” and “text” are not elements either. The actual question was if the space character after “some” and the one before “text” are _part of_ those inline boxes or not.

Comment: *In other words, no need to worry about whitespace as it is not an element.* --> a white space is a characater and yes you need to worry about because it's very important and we have many kind of whitespace (I know at least 4)

Comment: The OP is worried if whitespace needs to be taken into account. It does not. Whitespace is not relevant as it collapses if you were to take out the words. That is what the instructions say. And I don't appreciate the downvote on this one.

Comment: *Whitespace is not relevant as it collapses if you were to take out the words* --> they don't always collapse, there is a white-space algorithm that decide about this that you can change by changing the white-space property

Comment: @Temani Afif : Alright, please give me an example where you can add color and style to a white space.

Comment: @MistaPrime whitespace is non visible characters that occupy a space. It's not just ` ` but there're different types of spaces including nbsp, ensp etc.

Comment: @Sagar V. Thanks for stating the obvious. But is nbsp and ensp mentioned in the above?

Comment: They all comes under space. for example &ensp occupy a space for `n` and &emsp occupy a space for `m`

Comment: @Sagar V. That was what I attempted to describe in my initial answer. But the OP is worried about if whitespace needs to be taken into account for styling. It does not need to be taken into account. The anonymous element will be styled regardless if whitespace is there or not.